# What are the `LRE` and `PDF` characters that appear on my code when opening a file in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Do you know what the problem is, and how to fix it?

This happens when I open a simple .py file to Pycharm,

I'm using a Mac.

[image]

Comment: Where did you write the python file? Or, did you download it from online?

Comment: Please post your code inside of the question. Post the code in such a way that people can copy the code from stackoverflow.com and paste it into an IDE (like PyCharm). You uploaded a screen capture. I cannot copy an paste a `.png` screen capture into PyCharm. Nobody can answer your question unless they can run your code. We can't run/execute a .png file. Also, explain what the error is and only include the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the same error message.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon I think the OP is asking about the `LRE` and `PDF` characters appearing in the editor when opening a Python file in Pycharm. OP should clarify what the exact problem is, but it's probably not about running the code, and copying the code itself might be less clear than a screenshot in this case.

Answer (score 2):

These are Unicode characters indicating Left-Right Embedding and Pop Directional Formatting. These characters are included in text that is written in multiple languages where some of the languages are written right to left and other are written left to right. Each line then needs to be labelled with it's format and the PDF marks the end of a particular formatted block.

So my best guess is either you or whoever wrote this bit of code at one point had multiple languages written in it. Once that was the case, all the lines were reformatted to include these marker characters.